# Create a table when create a new user in WordPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, events

WordPress has an Admin Dashboard. In the dashboard we can add new users as an admin. I want to create a table in MySQL when a new user is added by the admin. For example I create a user named John Smith and its username is user1; When I add this user successfully, a table will be created in database named user1.

Comment: I don't know if it's a good practice to create a table for each user, but you can achive that , anyway, using `MySQL Triggers` : [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: What is the table data means columns?

Comment: @OnkarSingh yes a table with columns. But it's important to create a table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try in this way

```
add_action('user_register', 'custom_user_table_save', 10, 1);
function custom_user_table_save($user_id){
   require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
   global $wpdb;
   // get newly created username and create new table into DB
   $tablename = get_userdata($user_id)->user_login; 
   $table_create = "CREATE TABLE " . $tablename";";
   //  $wpdb->prefix want to add default WP db prefix to custom table otherwise remove it
   maybe_create_table( $wpdb->prefix . $tablename, $table_create );
}
```

Comment: I'm new with WordPress and I don't know how to use this piece of code?

Comment: It normally goes to you child-theme ```functions.php``` if you have child-theme or place it into active theme ```functions.php```